# Efficient way to change the format of a date in orgmode

Tags: org-table, query-replace-regexp

`enter code here`What would be the most efficient way to change the format of a list of dates like this in Emacs:

```
|Bob|1966/08/20|2023/05/19|
|Janice|1964/09/18|2023/05/19|
```

To this:

```
|Bob|<1966-08-20>|<2023-05-19>|
|Janice|<1964-09-18>|<2023-05-19>|
```

Would it be most efficient to use replace-regexp, rectangles, macros, the multiple cursor package, or something else?

In ed I am able to effect the change with two simple regular expressions:

```
g/\//s//-/g
g/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/s//<&>/g
```

Comment: `replace-regexp` seems to me to be be the natural fit here.

Comment: The first one should be `replace-regexp RET / RET -` and assumes that there are no other slashes around, but indeed, that's a perfectly good way to proceed. You need to be at the beginning of the buffer.

Comment: You deleted your comment! And this after (or during the time) I changed the answer to refer to it and added my previous comment :-) Ah, well - these things happen...

Comment: Sorry Nick. Self doubt crept in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do what you want:

```el
M-: (replace-regexp "\\([0-9]\\{4\\}\\)/\\([0-9]\\{2\\}\\)/\\([0-9]\\{2\\}\\)" "<\\1-\\2-\\3>" nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

This looks more complicated than it is because of the escaped backslashes: you could do `M-x replace-regexp` and then *type* the regexp in, in which case you'd only type a single backslash.

The regexp matches four digits, followed by a slash, followed by two digits, followed by a slash, followed by two digits. The groups of digits (year, month, day) are remembered (because they are inside `\( ... \)` ) and numbered 1, 2 and 3 resp. The replacement text then uses them by referring to them as `\1`, `\2` and `\3` (again the backslashes have to be doubled in lisp code).

The function is applied to a region (by default, starting from the current position of the cursor (the `point`) and going to the end of the buffer). Here we specify the beginning of the buffer (`(point-min)`) and the end of the buffer (`(point-max)`) so that the whole buffer is scanned).

There are many other ways to do this (e.g. two applications of `replace-regexp` with suitably modified versions of your `ed` regexps is another possibility - which I now see you have added in a comment!).

Regexps can be daunting and are overused in many cases, but there is no question that they are useful. See the Emacs manual, chapter [Searching and Replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search.html), for more info. And for even more, see the Emacs Lisp Reference manual, chapter [Searching and Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-and-Matching.html).

Comment: Beautifully elegant solution.